# 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly' not working showing loading... in google sign

Tags: flutter, google-api

```
Future googleSignIn() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly']).signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
}
```

> google API is not working

Comment: please define "not working"

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.
please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.  Good luck 

Comment: What's the error that you are seeing?

Comment: when I browse to that url I get a page that simply says: "contacts.readonly" (without the  quotes)